# Is there a way to mass reset multiple Prospect's mailability in Account Engagement?

Tags: pardot

We had some issues with the domain that one of our business units were trying to market from, resulting in a large number of prospect's emails hard bouncing back to us. They weren't bouncing because the prospect opted out, it was purely due to an issue with our domain. This has all been fixed now and I need to reset the mailability of approx 700 prospects so they can receive our marketing.

So far I've been resetting prospects mailability one-by-one, but naturally this is taking far too long.

Does anyone know how - if possible at all - to mass reset the mailability of multiple prospects who are currently classed as 'Undeliverable'?

Any guidance would be very appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Solved**

For anyone that may encounter this in the future, Salesforce Support can mass reset Prospect's mailability.

You can collate all affected Prospects via Account Engagement Reports, then provide Salesforce with all the relevant info and login in capabilities and they'll take care of the rest.

Comment: Instead of adding a bold title "Issue Solved", please mark your answer as solved. No need to put this in your own writing.